# How to listen to the event of another component from button in polymer 3

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x

I have a `paper-button` in one component and I need to fetch the data from other component when the button is clicked in the first Component. Can you help me how to do this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please post some code!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51559619/what-is-the-best-way-to-communicate-and-pass-data-between-child-polymer-elements/51560719#51560719

Comment: Thanks Hyyan it helped a lot

Comment: @PascalL. Sorry bud I needed the example concept I din had any code. whatever Hyyan suggested helps in understanding the concept